# How to move certain information from a row into columns in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched everywhere and couldn't find something that it's even close to what I'm looking for.
So I've  Excel sheets `SheetA` and `sheetB`.
On `sheetA`, I have row of information that is generated based on user input and Excel formulas in the row.
It looks something like this

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ProdCod1 | Prod1 | Value1 | SaleValue1 | ProdCod2 | Prod2 | Value2 | SaleValue2 | prodcod3 | … |

That is how the row looks like. In essence is a product that has variations and different price points.

What is very important to know is that some products will have values for: `prod1`, `prod2`, `prod3` some will have `prod2`, `prod6`, `prod7`

`Sheet2` I have all the products centralized.
This sheet looks like

| Column1. | Column2. | Column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prodcod1 | Prod1. | Value1. | Sale1 |
| ProdcodX. | ProdX. | ValueX. | SaleX |

The code should see what are the fields in the row of the first sheet that are available (I do have a cell in front of each product that mentions if its or not available, so can be used to determine if the set of info is need or not)
And add that information on the next available row in second sheet. (X+1)

My biggest issue is that if `prod1` is available and then `prod3` I can't find a logical formula that will determine the code what data to put from where to where

Ps. I am a novice so take me easy

To make it more clear please see below the excat 3 excel sheets:
[Main Sheet - the one that centralizes the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzY9k.png)

[Sheet with simple information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRm8a.png)

[The supplier that is a pain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvgkJ.png)

What happens is as following:
The user has Forms to complete. That information is captured in Sheet2 & 3 after passing through a calculation sheet specific for that supplier.

To have the products central when the user submits the form among other the first sheet is filled as well.
With the supplier that has product variation on the same row i have the problem. I need a solution to add that information to that sheet in the next row if is available.
At the moment i have a dim that defines the target row that relays on a CountA value.
Hope this gives more light and someone will be able to help.

this is the code that runs when the user clicks the Submit button:

```
'''' Dim TargetRow As Integer
            TargetRow = Sheets("Engine").Range("B31").Value

Dim Curs As Double
Curs = Sheets("Setari").Range("E2").Value

If Lab_AG925 = "DA" Then
'''ARGINT 925
Dim Cod925 As String
Cod925 = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("M7").Value
Dim RegularAG925 As Double
RegularAG925 = AG925_REGULAR

Dim SaleAG925 As Double
SaleAG925 = AG925_SALE

Dim ExtraAG925 As Double
ExtraAG925 = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("Z7").Value

Dim MinimAG925 As Double
MinimAG925 = AG925_MIN

Dim CostAG925 As Double
CostAG925 = AG925_COST

Dim Gram925 As Double
Gram925 = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("N7").Value

Dim Tag925 As String
Tag925 = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("U7").Value

'ID_Stuller
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 0).Value = TargetRow
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = Lab_CodGen
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value = Lab_Denumire
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 3).Value = Lab_Descriere
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value = Cod925
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 5).Value = CostAG925 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value = CostAG925 / Curs / Gram925
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 7).Value = Tag925
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 8).Value = RegularAG925 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 9).Value = RegularAG925 / Curs / Gram925
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 10).Value = SaleAG925 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 11).Value = SaleAG925 / Curs / Gram925
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 12).Value = ExtraAG925 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 13).Value = ExtraAG925 / Curs / Gram925
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 14).Value = MinimAG925 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 15).Value = MinimAG925 / Curs / Gram925
'''' Final ARGINT 925
End If

If Lab_AG950 = "DA" Then
'''ARGINT 950
Dim CodAG950 As String
CodAG950 = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("AE7").Value
Dim RegularAG950 As Double
RegularAG950 = AG950_REGULAR

Dim SaleAG950 As Double
SaleAG950 = AG950_SALE

Dim ExtraAG950 As Double
ExtraAG950 = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("AR7").Value

Dim MinimAG950 As Double
MinimAG950 = AG950_MIN

Dim CostAG950 As Double
CostAG950 = AG950_COST

Dim GramAG950 As Double
GramAG950 = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("AF7").Value

Dim TagAG950 As String
TagAG950 = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("AM7").Value

'ID_Stuller
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 16).Value = CodAG950
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 17).Value = CostAG950 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 18).Value = CostAG950 / Curs / GramAG950
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 19).Value = TagAG950
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 20).Value = RegularAG950 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 21).Value = RegularAG950 / Curs / GramAG950
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 22).Value = SaleAG950 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 23).Value = SaleAG950 / Curs / GramAG950
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 24).Value = ExtraAG950 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 25).Value = ExtraAG950 / Curs / GramAG950
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 26).Value = MinimAG950 / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 27).Value = MinimAG950 / Curs / GramAG950
'''' Final ARGINT 950
End If
If Lab_Platina = "DA" Then
'''ARGINT pLATINA
Dim CodPLATINA As String
CodPLATINA = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("AW7").Value
Dim RegularPLATINA As Double
RegularPLATINA = PLATINA_REGULAR

Dim SalePLATINA As Double
SalePLATINA = PLATINA_SALE

Dim ExtraPLATINA As Double
ExtraPLATINA = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("BJ7").Value

Dim MinimPLATINA As Double
MinimPLATINA = PLATINA_MIN

Dim CostPLATINA As Double
CostPLATINA = PLATINA_COST

Dim GramPLATINA As Double
GramPLATINA = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("AX7").Value

Dim TagPLATINA As String
TagPLATINA = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("BE7").Value

'ID_Stuller
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 28).Value = CodPLATINA
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 29).Value = CostPLATINA / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 30).Value = CostPLATINA / Curs / GramPLATINA
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 31).Value = TagPLATINA
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 32).Value = RegularPLATINA / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 33).Value = RegularPLATINA / Curs / GramPLATINA
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 34).Value = SalePLATINA / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 35).Value = SalePLATINA / Curs / GramPLATINA
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 36).Value = ExtraPLATINA / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 37).Value = ExtraPLATINA / Curs / GramPLATINA
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 38).Value = MinimPLATINA / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 39).Value = MinimPLATINA / Curs / GramPLATINA
'''' Final PLATINA
End If
If Lab_Paladiu = "DA" Then
'''Paladiu
Dim CodPALADIU As String
CodPALADIU = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("BO7").Value
Dim RegularPALADIU As Double
RegularPALADIU = PALADIU_REGULAR

Dim SalePALADIU As Double
SalePALADIU = PALADIU_SALE

Dim ExtraPALADIU As Double
ExtraPALADIU = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("CB7").Value

Dim MinimPALADIU As Double
MinimPALADIU = PALADIU_MIN

Dim CostPALADIU As Double
CostPALADIU = PALADIU_COST

Dim GramPALADIU As Double
GramPALADIU = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("BP7").Value

Dim TagPALADIU As String
TagPALADIU = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("BW7").Value

'ID_Stuller
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 40).Value = CodPALADIU
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 41).Value = CostPALADIU / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 42).Value = CostPALADIU / Curs / GramPALADIU
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 43).Value = TagPALADIU
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 44).Value = RegularPALADIU / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 45).Value = RegularPALADIU / Curs / GramPALADIU
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 46).Value = SalePALADIU / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 47).Value = SalePALADIU / Curs / GramPALADIU
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 48).Value = ExtraPALADIU / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 49).Value = ExtraPALADIU / Curs / GramPALADIU
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 50).Value = MinimPALADIU / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 51).Value = MinimPALADIU / Curs / GramPALADIU
'''' Final PALADIU
End If

If Lab_AU10K = "DA" Then
'''10K
Dim Cod10KAlb As String
Cod10KAlb = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("CG7").Value
Dim Cod10KGalben As String
Cod10KGalben = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("CH7").Value
Dim Cod10KRoz As String
Cod10KRoz = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("CI7").Value
Dim Regular10K As Double
Regular10K = AU10K_REGULAR

Dim Sale10K As Double
Sale10K = AU10K_SALE

Dim Extra10K As Double
Extra10K = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("CY7").Value

Dim Minim10K As Double
Minim10K = AU10K_MIN

Dim Cost10K As Double
Cost10K = AU10K_COST

Dim Gram10K As Double
Gram10K = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("CJ7").Value

Dim Tag10K As String
Tag10K = Sheets("Calc_Stuller").Range("CT7").Value

'ID_Stuller
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 52).Value = Cod10KAlb
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 53).Value = Cod10KGalben
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 54).Value = Cod10KRoz
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 55).Value = Cost10K / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 56).Value = Cost10K / Curs / Gram10K
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 57).Value = Tag10K
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 58).Value = Regular10K / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 59).Value = Regular10K / Curs / Gram10K
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 60).Value = Sale10K / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 61).Value = Sale10K / Curs / Gram10K
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 62).Value = Extra10K / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 63).Value = Extra10K / Curs / Gram10K
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 64).Value = Minim10K / Curs
Sheets("Stuller").Range("ID_Stuller").Offset(TargetRow, 65).Value = Minim10K / Curs / Gram10K
'''' Final 10K
End If
''''
```

here is where i am stuck. Normaly the data should be saved in a more simple central sheet that is name "Products"

Comment: To find a pattern in your data (to be able to find a rule) we need a set of example data that covers **all** possibilities of data occurences that should be covered by the code. Otherwise it is impossible to find that rule.

Comment: how can i add that in here. The 600 characters is not sufficient

Comment: Example means not *"entire data"* but [mcve] and you can [edit] your original question to add information that is necessary to understand your question.

Comment: i have add the cod as well that i have. what i need is the cod to add those information in another sheet in the next row on that sheet

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think VBA is the best way to solve your problem. I think this can be done without any code at all.

First, it looks like columns C:C and D:D are switched in the picture you shared of the supplier that is a pain. If that is the way you get it I would switch those two columns to start.

Next, I would make a new sheet that repeats the product name and descriptions over and over as many times as you need. You can copy and paste or use the below formula. ReplaceSheet1 with the name of your sheet.
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9999,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9999))+1)

Then, copy the data in columns C:C to M:M in (including the not available ones for now). This could be done with VBA if you want or you can just select C2:M5 and copy and paste.

Repeat this for each colored section (N2:X5, Y2:AI5, AJ2:AT5 in your example).

At this point you should have something similar to your Main Sheet photo but with the not available products included. To remove those just click Data -> Filter and then filter Available to No and delete those rows.

I hope that helps, please let me know if this is unclear